# PHP- strtotime not converting properly

Tags: php

I don't understand why `strtotime` is returning a date off by a few days.

```
$expiration = '2015-07-19'; // yyyy-mm-dd
$exp = strtotime($expiration);
$exp = date('F m, Y',$exp);

echo $exp; // returns "July 07, 2015" (NOT the 19th)
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE: Even if I do this:

```
echo date('F m, Y');
```

It says it's August 8 when today is August 21! Why!?!?!?

Comment: see my answer. m is a repesentation of a month use d instead to represent days. F is a full textual representation of a month. Therefore you are using two month representation in your date function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is: Outputs `July 19, 2015`. See demo. You are using two characters to represent months in your date function. F and m are textual and numeric representations of a month. So change '**m**' to '**d**' to represent days. `date("F d, Y") e.g. January 01, 2000`

```
$expiration = '2015-07-19'; // yyyy-mm-dd
$exp = strtotime($expiration);
$exp = date('F d, Y',$exp);

echo $exp;
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/181887)

Comment: @JROB F and m are month representations. You are not using a character to represent a day so use change m to d to represent days.

Comment: Wow, thank you. It's been a long day I can't believe I did that... thank you!

Comment: @JROB It's great to help you bro!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$expiration = '2015-07-19'; // yyyy-mm-dd
$exp = strtotime($expiration);
//$exp = date('F m, Y',$exp);
$exp = date('jS F, Y',$exp);
```

Output

```
19th July, 2015
```